# Copy Folder and its contents from one document library to another using Power Shell using filter

Tags: copy

How can i copy Folder and its contents from one document library to another using Power Shell if a column has "Yes" value on SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint on-premise or online?

Comment: @AnilPal This is for SharePoint on premises.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell to maintain file version history when moving/copying files between SharePoint sites: http://expert-advice.org/sharepoint/movemigrate-sharepoint-list-itemsdocuments-metadata-version-history/

Comment: Does this copy folder as well?